# Can compiler give warning when no explicit keyword used with one-argument constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-warnings

Sometimes I shoot myself in the foot by forgetting to use the "explicit" keyword for one-argument constructors. (I mean other than copy / move.) Is there a way to make the compiler give a warning in such cases?

Comment: Which compiler? Did you read its documentation to find out?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit GCC.

Comment: You might also check out Clang Tidy and CppCheck. They are static analyzers that probably have an option for something like this

Comment: GCC _what_? There have been tens if not hundreds of versions of GCC. _Be precise._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If GCC has an option to do this, I've not found it. Here is [a list of warning options in GCC 4.8.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html); refer to the similar documentation for your own version to be sure.

I use [CppCheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) to get this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Static code analyzers like cppcheck or clang-tidy will warn you and provide lots of other useful checks.